# Comparing subqueries results for inclusion

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following query:

```
select user as A
from table
where (
    select days
    from table
    where user = 123
) in (
    select days
    from table
    where user = A
)
```

Basically, I have a table with users and days that saves when a user logged in. Each user can login on different days, therefore I would have multiple rows for the same user.

I want all users who logged in every day that user 123 did (and maybe some more).

However, the above query gives the error:

> More than one value was returned by a sub-query.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The common solution to find matching sets is based on a self-join and counting:

```
WITH searched AS
 (
   SELECT DAYS -- list of dates to compare
   FROM table 
   WHERE USER=123
 )
SELECT
   t.User
   ,COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
   table as t
JOIN searched as s
ON t.DAYS = s.DAYS
GROUP BY 1
HAVING -- compare the number of rows matching those of user 123 
   cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM searched)
;
```

If there might be multiple rows per user/day you must join on DISTINCT dates.